# PoweredUp App for iOS: How to import/export my Project?

Tags: powered-up, ios

I'm running the official PoweredUp app (3.8.0) for iOS on a full-updated iPad Mini (iOS 15.4.1), and have created a custom Project (i.e. collection of blocks) in the App.

I cannot find an App option to export the Project.

Also I can't find the App's project files in the iPad Files App, or in Mac Finder when the iPad is connected via USB to the Mac.

I can do a full iPad backup to the Mac but I'm looking for a more targeted solution, for example to export the Project from the iPad and import it into another iPad or iPhone running the PoweredUp App.

I tried googling -- the only posted solutions refer to the Android App.

Answer (score 1):

You can't officially. Screenshot your project.